# Proof using existential quantifier

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Prove:

$$\begin{align} \exists x ~:~ \bigg(p(x) &\rightarrow q(x)\bigg) \

How do I go about proving this? Can I distribute the existential quantifier in the first term?

Comment: As I said [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959169/how-do-you-simplify-existential-quantifiers-in-logic#comment1971867_959169), if you want a formal a proof, you need to specify your rules.

Comment: Proof using laws of inference, please. Modus Tollens, Modus ponens, DeMorgan's, conjunctive simplification, disjunctive amplification..

Comment: Those are propositional calculus rules. This is predicate calculus statement. You can't prove this with those rules.

Comment: really? This is review in my discrete textbook. We are not incorporating any calculus into the course.

Comment: 'Calculus' here does not have the meaning you think it has. See the wikipedia entries [propositional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) and [predicate calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_logic). But yes, really.. What text book are you following?

Comment: Discrete and Combinatorical Mathematics by Grimaldi

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form

Comment: @Lil What bof says is right. You can find interpretations that make the statement false.

Comment: You have been using this site for 8 months, and you have asked 72 questions, but you have never accepted an answer nor cast a vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two relevant laws (whether they are laws of inference or not depends on your logic) would be:

$$A \rightarrow B \equiv \lnot A \lor B \tag{1}$$
$$\exists y ~:~ m(y) \lor n(y) \equiv \exists y ~:~ m(y) \lor \exists y ~:~  n(y)\tag{2}$$

Property **(1)** may as well be the definition of $\rightarrow$.  Property **(2)** is the result of $\exists$ being a quantified $\lor$.

To your question:

> Can I distribute the existential quantifier in the first term?

Let's apply properties **(1)** and **(2)** and see:

$$\exists x ~:~ p(x) \rightarrow q(x)$$
$$\exists x ~:~ \lnot p(x) \lor q(x)$$
$$\left(\exists x ~:~ \lnot p(x)\right) \lor \left(\exists x ~:~ q(x)\right)$$
$$\lnot \left(\exists x ~:~ \lnot p(x)\right) \rightarrow \left(\exists x ~:~ q(x)\right)$$ 
$$\left(\forall x ~:~ p(x)\right) \rightarrow \left(\exists x ~:~ q(x)\right)$$

So you see what happens when you try to distribute the $\exists$ across a $\rightarrow$.

> How do I go about proving this?

Simplify your expression.

$$\begin{align} \exists x ~:~ \bigg(p(x) &\rightarrow q(x)\bigg) \\
 &\rightarrow\\
 \bigg(\exists x ~:~ p(x) &\rightarrow \exists x ~:~ q(x)\bigg)\end{align}$$

Convert $\rightarrow$ to $\lor$:

$$\begin{align} \lnot(\exists x ~:~ \lnot p(x) &\lor q(x)) \\
 &\lor\\
 \bigg(\lnot \exists x ~:~ p(x) \bigg) &\lor \exists x ~:~ q(x)\end{align}$$

Carry through the $\lnot$ to the leaf terms:

$$\begin{align} (&\forall x ~:~ p(x) \land \lnot q(x)) \\
 &\lor \bigg(\forall x ~:~ \lnot p(x) \bigg) \\
 & \lor \exists x ~:~ q(x)\end{align}$$

Now you can probably find a counter example.  For a counter example, all 3 of the above *or* cases should be false.  The third case:
$$\exists x ~:~ q(x)$$
implies that a counter example must have $q(x) = \text{false}$.  So to find a counter example for:
$$\begin{align} (&\forall x ~:~ p(x)) \\
 &\lor \bigg(\forall x ~:~ \lnot p(x) \bigg) \\
 \end{align}$$
So your counter examples will be those situations where $p(x)$ is sometimes true and sometimes false, and when $q(x)$ is false.  In all other cases the statement is true.